# Remap lsp-mode prefix with use-package

Tags: key-bindings, use-package, lsp-mode

How do I remap the lsp-mode prefix key to "s-k" using the use-package package?

I tried the following

```
(use-package lsp-mode
  :ensure t
  :init
  (setq lsp-keymap-prefix (kbd "s-k")

 (use-package 
 [...]
 :bind
 ("s-k" . lsp-keymap-prefix)

 (use-package 
  [...] 
 :bind (:map lsp-command-map
 ("s-k" . lsp-keymap-prefix))
```

I don't seem to understand how this works. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 1:**
I am not sure if I should open a new issue for this.
I followed the suggested solutions without success, when another issue occured:

> Error (use-package): Failed to parse package lsp-mode: Wrong type
> argument: listp, lsp-keymap-prefix

Whene using emacs --debug-init, I get

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable personal-keybindings)
  byte-code("\3061\247\0\307\310N\206\13\0\311\307\312\"\210\313\310N\206\26\0\311\313\10\"\210\313\310N\206!\0\311\313\11\"\210\314\315!\2042\0\316\315\317\320\321$\210..." [read-process-output-max lsp-idle-delay name key kmap kdesc (debug error) gc-cons-threshold custom-set set-default 100000000 setq fboundp lsp autoload "lsp-mode" nil t lsp-command-map add-hook c++-mode-hook "s-k" vectorp read-kbd-macro key-description lookup-key assoc add-to-list personal-keybindings define-key :catch global-map binding details entry err use-package--warning1] 6)
  require(setup-lsp-mode)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/nry/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1076
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/nry/.emacs" "/home/nry/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" noerror nomessage)
  startup--load-user-init-file(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x158e8a4509ed>) #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x158e8a450a01>) t)
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

After a little more investigations, it turns out that this happens every time I use :bind, I had to comment out the :bind- statements from other packages as well to get rid of the error message. This was not the case before I started to change the prefix key! All I did was playing around with the bind-statements, like

```
(setq lsp-keymap-prefix (kbd "s-k")
```

and

```
  :bind
  ("s-k" . lsp-command-map) ;; not working

  :bind-keymap
  ("s-k" . lsp-command-map)
```

I set everything back as it was, but the error message stays (if I use :bind in other packages like e.g. company). But it ONLY stays, if I byte compile my directory. If I only use the .el files, no error occurs. It feels like I broke my config or the use-package package. Any sugggestions?

**EDIT 2:**
I found the solution to the issue describe in **EDIT 1**. I had to add

```
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'use-package))
```

to my .emacs file.
Also, changing the prefix-key was solved as well with:

```
  :bind-keymap
  ("s-k" . lsp-command-map)
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You want to set that variable to a string. This ought to work:

```
(use-package lsp-mode
  :init
  (setq lsp-keymap-prefix "s-k"))
```

You had `:ensure t` in there as well, but it doesn't have anything to do with configuring the package; instead it causes use-package to try to install lsp-mode if it isn't available. You might want to include it, or you might not.

The second form might in principle also work, with a little adjustment:

```
(use-package
  :bind
  ("s-k" . lsp-command-map)
```

However, when lsp-mode is loaded it will still use the `lsp-command-prefix` variable to set up a key binding that loads `lsp-command-map` as the active keyboard map; it's likely that you would end up with two prefix keys that lead to this same set of commands. Not fatal, but potentially confusing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Unfortunately, another error occurred (see edit) and I cannot 100% confirm if any of the provided solutions work for me.

Comment: :bind-keymap ("s-k" . lsp-command-map) did the trick :)

Comment: For me, setting `lsp-keymap-prefix` successfully changes the variable, with no error message, but it doesn't affect the binding.  My key combination remains unbound.

Comment: @NormanRamsey, you should create a new question with all relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/1532), you need to use `bind-keymap` and not just `bind` because this is really a keymap you are binding, not a function.

The following worked for me:

```
  :bind-keymap
  ("<f11>" . lsp-command-map)
```